# Change text color of custom view from xml file in android

Tags: java, android, android-custom-view

I am learn to create custom view in android. I created Component with name JFXButton. But i am facing issue while setTextColor() from JFXButton. when i try to replace color from xml file it does not change color. JFXButton extends AppCompactButton. Suggest me proper way to do it.

here is the full code.

**JFXButton.java**

```
public class JFXButton extends AppCompatButton {

    @DrawableRes
    private static final int DEFAULT_BUTTON = R.drawable.common_primary_btn;

    private ButtonDesignType mButtonDesignType;
    private int mChangeColor;

    public JFXButton(Context context) {
        super(context);
        init(context, null, 0);
    }

    public JFXButton(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        init(context, attrs, 0);
    }

    public JFXButton(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
        init(context, attrs, defStyle);
    }

    private void init(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
        // Load attributes
        final TypedArray a = context.obtainStyledAttributes(
                attrs, R.styleable.JFXButton, defStyle, 0);

        if (attrs == null) {
            return;
        }
        
        mButtonDesignType = ButtonDesignType.get(a.getInt(R.styleable.JFXButton_buttonDesignType, 0));

        if (!a.hasValue(R.styleable.JFXButton_buttonDesignType)) {
            setBackground(getResources().getDrawable(DEFAULT_BUTTON));
        }
        setButtonDesign();
        setTextColor(Color.GREEN);
        a.recycle();

    }

    @SuppressLint("UseCompatLoadingForDrawables")
    private void setButtonDesign() {
        if (mButtonDesignType == ButtonDesignType.Cancel) {
            setBackground(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.common_cancel_btn));
        } else if (mButtonDesignType == ButtonDesignType.SaveAndClose) {
            setBackground(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.common_save_and_close_btn));
        } else if (mButtonDesignType == ButtonDesignType.Save) {
            setBackground(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.common_save_btn));
        } else if (mButtonDesignType == ButtonDesignType.Close) {
            setBackground(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.common_close_btn));
        } else if (mButtonDesignType == ButtonDesignType.Primary) {
            setBackground(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.common_primary_btn));
        } else if (mButtonDesignType == ButtonDesignType.Plain) {
            setBackground(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.common_plain_btn));
        } else if (mButtonDesignType == ButtonDesignType.Done) {
            setBackground(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.done_cancelv3_btn));
        } else if (mButtonDesignType == ButtonDesignType.CancelV3) {
            setBackground(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.done_cancelv3_btn));
        }
    }


    public ButtonDesignType getmButtonDesignType() {
        return mButtonDesignType;
    }

    public void setmButtonDesignType(ButtonDesignType mButtonDesignType) {
        this.mButtonDesignType = mButtonDesignType;
        invalidate();
        requestLayout();
    }
}
```

**attr_jfx_button.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <declare-styleable name="JFXButton">
        <attr name="buttonDesignType" format="enum">
            <enum name="Cancel" value="0"/>
            <enum name="SaveAndClose" value="1"/>
            <enum name="Save" value="2"/>
            <enum name="Close" value="3"/>
            <enum name="Primary" value="4"/>
            <enum name="Plain" value="5"/>
            <enum name="Done" value="6"/>
            <enum name="CancelV3" value="7"/>
        </attr>
    </declare-styleable>
</resources>
```

**layout_main.xml**

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">


    <com.uniberse.unibersereataurent.ui.JFXButton
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/_50sdp"
        android:text="JFXButton"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:textSize="@dimen/_18sdp"
        app:buttonDesignType="Done" />


</LinearLayout>
```

Help me to solve this problem.
Thank You

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution.
We need to define Button attribute without format in our attribute file. and we can able to change the color from xml. so final code is as below:

**JFXButton.java**

```
public class JFXButton extends AppCompatButton {

    @DrawableRes
    private static final int DEFAULT_BUTTON = R.drawable.common_primary_btn;

    private ButtonDesignType mButtonDesignType;
    private int mChangeColor;

    public JFXButton(Context context) {
        super(context);
        init(context, null, 0);
    }

    public JFXButton(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        init(context, attrs, 0);
    }

    public JFXButton(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
        init(context, attrs, defStyle);
    }

    private void init(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
        // Load attributes
        final TypedArray a = context.obtainStyledAttributes(
                attrs, R.styleable.JFXButton, defStyle, 0);

        if (attrs == null) {
            return;
        }
        
        mButtonDesignType = ButtonDesignType.get(a.getInt(R.styleable.JFXButton_buttonDesignType, 0));
        int textColor = a.getColor(R.styleable.JFXButton_android_textColor, Color.BLACK);

        if (!a.hasValue(R.styleable.JFXButton_buttonDesignType)) {
            setBackground(getResources().getDrawable(DEFAULT_BUTTON));
        }
        setButtonDesign();
        setTextColor(textColor);
        a.recycle();

    }

    @SuppressLint("UseCompatLoadingForDrawables")
    private void setButtonDesign() {
        if (mButtonDesignType == ButtonDesignType.Cancel) {
            setBackground(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.common_cancel_btn));
        } else if (mButtonDesignType == ButtonDesignType.SaveAndClose) {
            setBackground(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.common_save_and_close_btn));
        } else if (mButtonDesignType == ButtonDesignType.Save) {
            setBackground(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.common_save_btn));
        } else if (mButtonDesignType == ButtonDesignType.Close) {
            setBackground(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.common_close_btn));
        } else if (mButtonDesignType == ButtonDesignType.Primary) {
            setBackground(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.common_primary_btn));
        } else if (mButtonDesignType == ButtonDesignType.Plain) {
            setBackground(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.common_plain_btn));
        } else if (mButtonDesignType == ButtonDesignType.Done) {
            setBackground(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.done_cancelv3_btn));
        } else if (mButtonDesignType == ButtonDesignType.CancelV3) {
            setBackground(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.done_cancelv3_btn));
        }
    }


    public ButtonDesignType getmButtonDesignType() {
        return mButtonDesignType;
    }

    public void setmButtonDesignType(ButtonDesignType mButtonDesignType) {
        this.mButtonDesignType = mButtonDesignType;
        invalidate();
        requestLayout();
    }
}
```

**attr_jfx_button.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <declare-styleable name="JFXButton">
        <attr name="buttonDesignType" format="enum">
            <enum name="Cancel" value="0"/>
            <enum name="SaveAndClose" value="1"/>
            <enum name="Save" value="2"/>
            <enum name="Close" value="3"/>
            <enum name="Primary" value="4"/>
            <enum name="Plain" value="5"/>
            <enum name="Done" value="6"/>
            <enum name="CancelV3" value="7"/>
        </attr>
        <attr name="android:textColor" />
        <attr name="android:textSize" />
        <attr name="android:text" />
        <attr name="android:background" />
    </declare-styleable>
</resources>
```

**layout_main.xml**

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">


    <com.uniberse.unibersereataurent.ui.JFXButton
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/_50sdp"
        android:text="JFXButton"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:textSize="@dimen/_18sdp"
        app:buttonDesignType="Done" />


</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add `app:backgroundTint="@null"` to the xml of the button